# App is crashing because a method is being deallocated

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have this code that creates 40 UITextFields in a UIPopover; when I try to put a number in one of the textFields, the app crashes with this:

> -[ImportTABDelimitedFile respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance

This is the code to create the textfields:

```
//  create the uitextfields for user to match against their input file columns
CGRect nbrFieldRect = CGRectMake(x-20, y, 26.0f, 26.0f);
UITextField *nbrTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:nbrFieldRect];
if(colorYES)
    nbrTextField.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(0xFFF9AF);
else
    nbrTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

nbrTextField.enabled = YES;
[nbrTextField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];
nbrTextField.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
nbrTextField.tag = tagNumber + 100;  //  range: 170-215
nbrTextField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0f];
nbrTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
nbrTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
nbrTextField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
[nbrTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(mapUserFields) forControlEvents: UIControlEventEditingDidEnd];
nbrTextField.delegate = self;
[theView addSubview:nbrTextField];
```

And this is the code for *mapUserFields*:

```
-(void)mapUserFields  {

    NSLog(@"mapUserFields: textFieldDidEndEditing");
}
```

**UPDATE #2**  I ran Instruments, and it shows that the *method* is being deallocated, which is causing the crash; this is the image of the Instruments output:
[image]

Now, the question is: why is *the method* being deallocated, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Empty textField.delegate could not cause a crash. Your issue is somewhere else.

Comment: what makes you think it is the delegate fault? I have a feeling that 40 uitextfields object being released has to do with this.

Comment: @meda: they are added to the view, there for they are no released. at least not from the code we see here.

Answer (score 2):

You add the delegate when you create the text field and setup its other properties, like this:

```
UITextField *nbrTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:nbrFieldRect];
nbrTextField.delegate = self;
```

and implement its delegate method which is called when you press enter key from keyboard:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

The above code you posted looks fine so far, until you post the logs of crash.

**EDIT**:The crash logs you posted suggest the object (`ImportTABDelimitedFile` in this case) which is added as observer for `UIControlEventEditingDidEnd` event of text field is being deallocated.

Can you make sure one thing that you retain popover in your presenting class, by creating a property with retain type and when you dismiss the property set `nil` to the popover variable. For example like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPopoverController *popoverController;
```

and don't forget to initialize and assign this property when you present popover. Set its delegate to self like this:

```
popoverController.delegate = self;
```

Don't forget to implement delegate and in the delegate method, do clear the property variable like this:

```
- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController{
    self.popoverController = nil; //if you are using non-arc, release it.
}
```

Comment: and what selector is send?

Comment: @spokane-dude see my edited answer based on the crash log you provided.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem (with the help of Michael Dautermann)...  I had to make the called method a property like:

```
iTABFile = [[ImportTABDelimitedFile alloc]init];
```

Now, it's not released, and works like a champ!  Thank you everybody for your help; I really appreciate it.  SD

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing a bit here not seeing the rest of the code, but you need to do two things. Firstly, set up the class that is creating all the textFields to conform to the UITextFieldDelegate protocol. I am asssuming the class you have pasted the code above is the one.

This is done in the header file (the .h)

Likewise, when creating your 40-odd textfields, setting:

```
nbrTextField.delegate = self;
```

Will have the current class act as the delegate for the UITextFields.

Hope this helps